# How do I format the contents of the following variable in Python?

Tags: python, string, format, python-requests, beautifulsoup

So, I have been playing around with requests and bs4 for a project I'm working on and have managed to return the following in a variable:

"----------

Crossways Inn

Withy Road
West Huntspill
Somerset
TA93RA

01278783756
www.crosswaysinn.com

----------"

This was scraped from a site, using .text function within the bs4 module.

Is there any way I can format this within my program to look like the following:

"----------\n
Crossways Inn\n
Withy Road\n
West Huntspill\n
Somerset\n
TA93RA\n
01278783756\n
www.crosswaysinn.com\n
----------\n"

Sorry for the vague explanation of what I want to do, but do not know how to explain it better. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to display it (print it) so it looks like the latter?

Comment: @dkasak Yes, that'd work.

Comment: Could you post the beautifulsoup-related part - the way you are scraping the data? There might be a way to fix/improve it there.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `repr()`

Like:

`print(repr(<variable with string>))`